# Unable to render Listblock inside StreamBlock in template Wagtail

Tags: python, django-templates, wagtail

I have StructBlock inside a Listblock, all of which sit insde a class BannerBlock as follows:

```
class BannerBlock(blocks.StreamBlock):
    """
    Blocks for displaying individual banners
    """
    
    banners = blocks.ListBlock(
        blocks.StructBlock(
            [
                ('image', ImageChooserBlock(required=True)),
                ('title', blocks.CharBlock(required=True, max_length=128)),
                ('description', blocks.CharBlock(required=True, max_length=1024)),
                ('link', blocks.URLBlock(required=False)),
            ]
        )
    )
    
    class Meta:
        template = "home/banner_block.html"
        icon = "placeholder"
        label = "Banners"
```

The template Banner_block is as follows:

```
{% load wagtailimages_tags %}

<!-- Banner -->
<div id="banner">
    {% for banner in self.banners %}
        <article data-position="bottom right">
            <div class="inner">
                {% image banner.image original as image %}
                <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="">
                <div class="features">
                    <a href="{{ banner.link.url }}" class="c-accent alt no-bg">
                    <h2>{{ banner.title }}</h2>
                    <p>{{ banner.description }}</p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Finally, I am trying to render each Banner (Listblock) as follows:

```
{% for block in page.banners_collection %}
     {% include_block block %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, Each Listblock is rendered as plain text as list items.
How do I render each item correctly?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the `banners_collection` field on your page model is defined as:

```
banners_collection = StreamField(BannerBlock())
```

where you're specifying a StreamBlock to use at the top level of the StreamField, rather than the more basic setup of

```
some_stream = StreamField([
    ('first_block_type', some_block_definition),
    ('another_block_type', some_block_definition),
])
```

where you pass a list of blocks for StreamField to make a stream from. This means that when you access `page.banners_collection`, it will give you a single instance of a BannerBlock value. When you loop over this value with `for block in page.banners_collection`, you're actually getting back the ListBlock values in your stream, and rendering them individually with `include_block` - bypassing the template you set up for BannerBlock. Your `ListBlock` values don't have a template of their own, so they end up using the default rendering.

If you call `include_block` on the BannerBlock value as a whole:

```
{% include_block page.banners_collection %}
```

then it will use your template. However, there's a secondary problem - in the line

```
{% for banner in self.banners %}
```

`self.banners` is not valid, because a stream value behaves as a sequence, not a dictionary. You can't look up the `banners` children by name - you need to loop over the list of children finding the ones that are of type `banners`. (Except, in your case, you can skip that check because `banners` is the only available block type within the stream). The correct template code would look like:

```
<div id="banner">
    {% for block in self %}
        {# the 'block' object here has properties block_type (which is always 'banners' here) and value #}
        {% for banner in block.value %}
            {# banner is a StructBlock value, with image, title, description, link properties #}
            <article data-position="bottom right">
                <div class="inner">
                    {% image banner.image original as image %}
                    ...
               </div>
           </article>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

However, are you sure you need the ListBlock in addition to the StreamBlock? A StreamBlock is already a sequence of blocks, so a ListBlock inside a StreamBlock gives you a list of *lists of banners*. If you simplified the BannerBlock value to

```
class BannerBlock(blocks.StreamBlock):
    """
    Blocks for displaying individual banners
    """
    
    banner = blocks.StructBlock(
        [
            ('image', ImageChooserBlock(required=True)),
            ('title', blocks.CharBlock(required=True, max_length=128)),
            ('description', blocks.CharBlock(required=True, max_length=1024)),
            ('link', blocks.URLBlock(required=False)),
        ]
    )
    
    class Meta:
        template = "home/banner_block.html"
        icon = "placeholder"
        label = "Banners"
```

then BannerBlock as a whole would be a list of banners, and the template would become

```
<div id="banner">
    {% for block in self %}
        {# block.value is now a StructBlock value #}
        <article data-position="bottom right">
            <div class="inner">
                {% image block.value.image original as image %}
                ...
           </div>
       </article>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```